# Can I generate Beta(of stocks) for all columns (holding stocks returns) at one go without having to loop through each column in a Pandas frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) which holds the monthly returns of multiple stocks (in columns). The last column is the benchmark return. The dataframe index is the end of the month date in YYYYMM format. I need to generate the  betas for each of the stocks. While I can loop through each column and generate the respective betas, I am hoping with Python there is a more elegant solution not involving loops. Can someone please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Write function to calculate β which takes in your returns in columns. Use `df.apply(beta_func)`

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try this.

Comment: I suspect you need 2 time series to calculate β, the stock and the market. So a better approach would be to write a function that takes in stock returns and market returns, which still will iterate through the columns of stock df. If you're in search for something better, show your code and tell us where you woud like to improve it.

Comment: Yes. I have ~ 150 stocks returns (T.S. 1) and one vector of market returns (T.S. 2). I need the beta for each one of those 150 stocks. While I can write a loop and run through each combination of stock and market return, I am hoping Python has a more elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: There always be a loop, either a for loop which you see, or a hidden one via `df.apply()`. You may hide it into a function though if you wish to reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a loop you'll have to do some matrix multiplication with numpy. E.g.

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

# download prices
tickers = ['PYPL', 'JPM', 'NKE']
stock = data.DataReader(tickers, 'yahoo', '2019-08-31', '2020-08-31')
bench = data.DataReader('^GSPC', 'yahoo', '2019-08-31', '2020-08-31')

# returns from prices
bench_returns = bench['Adj Close'].pct_change()[1:]
stock_returns = stock['Adj Close'].pct_change()[1:]

# Matrix multiplication
A = np.array(bench_returns)
B = np.array(stock_returns)

betas = 1 / np.dot(A, A.transpose()) * np.dot(A.transpose(), B)
betas
```

Result:

```
array([1.16944123, 1.31768569, 0.9873832 ])
```